# ChefSpec and Ark resources testing

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo, cookbook, chefspec

I'm starting to test with chefspec, which i think is a really easy and reliable test framework. But i'm having some issues regarding to ark resources testing.
I have this default_spec.rb

```
require 'chefspec'
require_relative 'spec_helper'

describe 'df-maven::default' do
  let (:chef_run) { ChefSpec::Runner.new.converge(described_recipe) }
  it 'should run ark' do
    expect(chef_run).to put_ark #'described_'
  end
end
```

Which is the test i want for my recipe `df-maven::default`:

```
include_recipe 'java::default'
include_recipe 'ark::default'

mvn_version = node['df-maven']['version'].to_s

ark 'maven' do
  url      node['df-maven'][mvn_version]['url']
  checksum node['df-maven'][mvn_version]['checksum']
  path     node['df-maven']['m2_home']
  version  node['df-maven'][mvn_version]['version']
  has_binaries ['bin/mvn']
  append_env_path true
  action :put
end
```

But when i run the test i get an error `undefined local variable or method 'put_ark'`.

Then i added this to my spec_helper (as i think matchers should do the trick):

```
require 'chefspec'

module ChefSpec
  module Matchers
    RSpec::Matchers.define :put_ark do |package_name|
      match do |chef_run|
        chef_run.resources.any? do |resource|
          resource_type(resource) == 'ark' and resource.name == package_name
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But i get a `undefined method resources' for #<ChefSpec::Runner:0x40a2650>` error

In the real practice, it does what it is required to do, but i was asked to start making tests for all my cookbooks, so i decided to start with my df-maven cookbook.

Anyway, I think i have to define matchers, but i don't understand how to do it and make my tests to pass.

Comment: @Rob3 Please stop suggesting minor edits. You've got a complete history of suggesting edits regarding capitalization of "I" only. That's not OK, even if most of them get robo-approved.

Comment: @Sergiu Paraschiv the lowercase "i" in english is a gramatical error. Write a uppercase "I" is the right way. Who write a right sentence transmitted a right idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in the [ChefSpec README](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#packaging-custom-matchers), in `libraries/matchers.rb` (for autoloading):

```rb
if defined?(ChefSpec)
  def put_ark(resource_name)
    ChefSpec::Matchers::ResourceMatcher.new(:ark, :put, resource_name)
  end
end
```

If you don't want to distribute this matcher, you can put it in `spec/support/something.rb`:

```
def put_ark(resource_name)
  ChefSpec::Matchers::ResourceMatcher.new(:ark, :put, resource_name)
end
```

And then require 'spec/support/something' in your `spec_helper.rb`.

This will make a `put_ark` resource matcher/